# How to view call stack of C code called via .Call() in R

Tags: c, r, callstack

Basically it's all in the title.  I'm calling C code from R via .Call().  The C code is throwing an error, but using traceback() or options(error=recover), the .Call() function is the farthest I can drill down to.  Is there a way to view the C call stack when an error is thrown in the C code?

Comment: There is some useful information regarding `.Call` in sections 5.9 and 5.10 of [Writing R Extensions](http://www.math.ncu.edu.tw/~chenwc/R_note/reference/package/R-exts.pdf).  One sentence that popped out at me was "Before you decide to use `.Call` or `.External`, you should look at other alternatives."

Comment: @RichardScriven: But the recent consensus is *clearly* in favour of not using `.C` -- see eg the recent NEWS file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use gdb (or lldb under clang) to debug C code, perhaps as outlined [here](http://bioconductor.org/developers/how-to/c-debugging/)